# Does coinbase charge for gas fees?

Tags: gas, fees, coinbase

I'm reading this [article](https://blog.shrimpy.io/blog/coinbase-vs-uniswap) which says coinbase could charge you for gas fees.

> However, when Ethereum gets congested, Coinbase will charge you for
> gas fees too. When it comes to gas, Uniswap and Coinbase are a wash.

Is this actually true?

The [fee page](https://help.coinbase.com/en/pro/trading-and-funding/trading-rules-and-fees/fees) on coinbase makes no mention of gas fees.

Comment: Hello nz_21, you may want to try ethereum.SE for questions about Ethereum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly off-topic, as it's about a third-party application...

For Coinbase Pro, the article is correct as of September 2020, as per [this](https://twitter.com/CoinbasePro/status/1306641678506360832?s=20) Tweet:

> Starting today, Coinbase Pro will pass along network fees directly to
> our customers. These fees (sometimes referred to as “gas fees” on the
> Eth blockchain) are paid directly to crypto miners that process
> transactions and secure the respective network.

Comment: That's interesting...given that coinbase is just a centralized exchange, I'm curious how gas fees come into play at all here.